# How to keep my custom range/slider follower div perfectly centered with range thumb in Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've spent some time working on a slider that has a div follow the thumb of slider. I did this by creating a relatively positioned container for the follower (called `#slider-follower-cntnr`). I then adjust the position of the follower div (`#slider-follower`) according to the value of the range input. The problem is that as you move the thumb across the track the follower does not stay perfectly centered against the position of the thumb. I've tried adjusting the width of the `#slider-follower-cntnr` but I don't no how to find the correct width to keep it perfectly centered. Thanks for any help.

**TL/DR**: How can I keep follower div centered perfectly to the thumb of the range input across all range values?

[Heres a codepen.](http://codepen.io/danielyaa5/pen/MKxOZJ) You may need to full screen to see it get off center as you pull it along the range.

### HTML

```
<div id="slider-cntnr">
  <input type="range" id="frame-slider" oninput="updateFollowerValue(this.value)" />
  <div id="slider-follow-cntnr">
    <div id="slider-follow">
      <div id="slider-val-cntnr">
        <span id="slider-val"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### JS

```
var follower = document.getElementById('slider-follow');
var follower_val = document.getElementById('slider-val');
var slider = document.getElementById('frame-slider');

var updateFollowerValue = function(val) {
  follower_val.innerHTML = val;
  follower.style.left = (val*1) + '%';
};

updateFollowerValue(slider.value);
```

### CSS

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#slider-cntnr {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 40px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: orange;
}

#frame-slider {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#slider-follow-cntnr {
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 98%;
}

#slider-follow {
  background-color: black;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

#slider-val-cntnr {
  background-color: white;
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
}

#slider-val {
  margin-left: 9px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few ways you can fix this:

(1) In the HTML

```
  <div id="slider-val-cntnr">
    <center>
    <span id="slider-val"></span>
    </center>
  </div>
```

(2) In the CSS

```
#slider-val {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

(1) The HTML method probably works the best, but it's generally not best practice to have `<center>` tags throughout your HTML.

(2) This will make sure that the number never goes beyond the bounds of the white box that it resides in. If you don't care that it is absolutely centered, and just want the number to not exit the box, then this is a suitable solution.